# jumping to the a wanted line and overriding the first letter inside it in c

Tags: c, printf

hello i am trying to write to a FILE in a wanted line number using c programming language
and for some unknown reasons it doesnt get written
this is my checking code:

```
int main()
{
    int x;
    int counter = 0;
    char buffer[MAX];
    FILE* fp = fopen("sale_day.txt","w");
    fprintf(fp,"5 orange 11\n");
    fprintf(fp,"4 pelephone 222\n");
    fprintf(fp,"3 mirs 4000\n");
    fprintf(fp,"2 cellcom 302\n");
    fprintf(fp,"1 tmobile 500\n");
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("sale_day.txt","r+");
    while (counter < 2)
    {// jumping two rows
        fgets(buffer,MAX,fp);// i tried using fscanf which didnt help aswell
        counter++;
    }
    fflush(fp); // i tried with and without still doesnt work
    fputs("$",fp);
    fflush(fp); // i tried with and without still doesnt work
    fclose(fp);
}
```

i expect to get :

```
5 orange 11
4 pelephone 222
$ mirs 4000
2 cellcom 302
1 tmobile 500
```

for some reason it stays as the following in "sale_day.txt" file

```
5 orange 11
4 pelephone 222
3 mirs 4000
2 cellcom 302
1 tmobile 500
```

even tho when i debug it it shows a "$" instead of the 3 digit

thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: what do you mean by inside a line?

Comment: i want to override the first letter inside the line which i get to 
with $

Comment: did you tried with a file manually created by you ? (just ran it , comment ..FILE* fp = fopen("sale_day.txt","w"); ... Fclose(fp);...

Comment: i wrote all of the file using c just as mentioned in my question ,i didnt create the file in windows using create new text document

Comment: `fflush` may actually be the problem. Check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/cc146ee9-8c13-4b61-8c0b-6f40b6f0b9b2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you expecting?  When I run your code, I get:

```
5 orange 11
4 pelephone 222
$ mirs 4000
2 cellcom 302
1 tmobile 500
```

This is exactly right given what you've coded:  read two lines (leaving you positioned at the third line), and write a `$` char.

Note that file write operations overwrite existing file data, or append new data to the end of a file.  They don't *insert* data (which may have been the operation you're expecting).

Comment: i expect to get what u just wrote ... when i open the file using notepad it shows a "3" instead of $ for some reason, when i debug it it says that it has $ maybe something is wrong with my compiler ... i got no clue :(

Answer (score 1):

The code works just fine, also without the `fflush`-lines. After running the program, line 3 is changed as follows:

Before:

`3 mirs 4000`

After:

`$ mirs 4000`

I ran your code like it is, only with this on top:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 255
```

Comment: for me it does not work using visual studio 10
inside the debugger it change but inside the text file which i am trying to read it does not get changed

Comment: did u not run it on visual studio ?

Comment: No, I compiled with gcc and run in Ubuntu. I noticed that the MSDN documentation for fopen states that you should have `fflush` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb(v=vs.80).aspx) when you change between reading and writing from a file opened using `r+`, so the `fflush` you do before writing `$` is fine.

Comment: thanks for your replay i am trying to figure out how do deal with this annoying bug that i am having in visual studio ... fflush doesnt help but in the link that you posted it is mentioned that there as to be an fflush / fsetpos or rewind operation(fflush doesnt help), do you know how to handle it ?

Comment: `fflush` may actually be the problem. Check out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/cc146ee9-8c13-4b61-8c0b-6f40b6f0b9b2